# "ion-datetime" default time not equal now time in ionic2

Tags: date, time, ionic2

I have small issue with "ion-datetime"

I want to change the default time of "ion-datetime" to make it such as today date, time.

So how can I change the default value of "ion-datetime" in ionic 2 because when I click on input field, the application show me the time reduced by 3 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript time library are not well matched for IONIC ISO 8601 Datetime Format
I recommend using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

1. Go to you folder application, run : `npm install moment --save`
2. In your page.ts add: `import * as moment from 'moment';`
3. Declare your variable: `myDate= moment().format();`
4. Now just use [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) like this:

   ```
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
   ```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:
    In your.ts File:
    let current_datetime: any;

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
let Today = new Date().toISOString();
let date = String(Today).substr(0,10)
let Time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
this.current_datetime = date+" "+Time;
```

}

```
In Your .html File:


<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss" [(ngModel)]="current_datetime"></ion-datetime>
```